# .NET MAUI; Button font color bug?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

So when I am using Button's, I get a weird result. If I make a button or use the maui sample project, the font colorwill always be black.
So lets break it down:

1. I have a button with white font color.
2. I hover over the button and the fotn color turns black.
3. I hover away from the button and the color STAYS black.

Am I missing something in my buttons? Does anybody else experience this?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        Title = "Button test";

        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout { Margin = new Thickness(20) };

        Label label = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Button test."
        }; 

        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "click here.",

        };

        stackLayout.Add(label);
        stackLayout.Add(button);

        Content = stackLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems an issue that RadioButtonExtensions.UpdateTextColor applies to not only radiobutton but all the button.And
as you can see here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/4998. this issue will be fixed.